How to add tab navigations dynamically in react native expo?
The Image I am trying to achieve
I want to have something like the above image where every tab item in the tab navigation represents a date and it can represent infinite amount of date dynamically.
I am currently trying this:
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import { withLayoutContext } from "expo-router";
import React from "react";

const { Navigator } = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const MaterialTopTabs = withLayoutContext(Navigator);

export const dataPoints = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Tab 1' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Tab 2' },
    { id: 3, title: 'Tab 3' },
    // more data
];


export default function MatchTabsLayout() {
    return (
        <MaterialTopTabs
            screenOptions={{}}
        >
            {dataPoints.map((dataPoint) => (
                <MaterialTopTabs.Screen
                    key={dataPoint.id}
                    name={`Tab-${dataPoint.id}`}
                    initialParams={{ title: dataPoint.title }}
                />
            ))}
        </MaterialTopTabs>
    );
}

But it's not working.
Also here's my folder structure:
└── app/
    └── (tabs)/
        ├── _layout.jsx
        ├── index.jsx

Can someone please help me answer how to achive this layout of dynamic tabs?
